# WSO2 API Manager who can subcriber to APIs in Developer Page

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

API Manager 3.0.0 in Carbon page, if a new user and assign this roles:
[image: Roles for the new user]

For this user is possible to login in Developer page and subscriber, for **ALL** APIs of API products exists.

But If exist 3 users: **A, B, C** and 3 APIs: **X, Y, Z**.

1. The user **A** could subscriber for **ALL** APIs
2. The user **B** could subscriber only for API **Y**
3. The user **C** could subscriber APIs **X and Y**

Is possible to do the scenario with the user A,B and C and APIs X,Y and Z?
How?

**Thanks**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can set API visibility using roles.

[image]

More details: https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.0.0/learn/design-api/advanced-topics/control-api-visibility-and-subscription-availability-in-developer-portal/